pandas.DataFrame.fillna with booleans?
I have 2 dataframes, one that contains data and one that contains exlusions that need to be merged onto the data and marked as included(True or False).  I have been doing this as follows for a couple of years by simply adding a new column to the exclusions data frame and setting everything to True, then merging that onto the main dataframe which results in the additional column containing either True or NaN.  Finally I run a pd.fillna to replace all the NaN values with False and I'm good to go.
import pandas as pd
MainData = {'name':  ['apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'watermelon'],
            'other': ['blah' , 'blah', 'blah'  , 'blah']}
dfMainData = pd.DataFrame(MainData)
Exclusions = {'name':   ['pear'      , 'watermelon'],
              'reason': ['pears suck', 'too messy!']}
dfExclusions = pd.DataFrame(Exclusions)
dfExclusions['excluded'] = True

dfMainData = pd.merge(dfMainData, dfExclusions, how='left', on='name')
dfMainData['excluded'] = dfMainData['excluded'].fillna(False)

I was previously running pands 1.2.4 but am making code updates and am migrating to 2.2.1 as part of this, and am now receiving the following warning:

dfMainData['excluded'] = dfMainData['excluded'].fillna(False)
:1: FutureWarning: Downcasting object dtype arrays on .fillna, .ffill, .bfill is deprecated and will change in a future version. Call result.infer_objects(copy=False) instead. To opt-in to the future behavior, set pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)

It still technically works but it appears that this is NOT the pandas'esque way of doing things, so I am curious how I should be going about this now to avoid compatibility issues in the future?

Does this answer your question? pandas FutureWarning: Downcasting object dtype arrays on .fillna, .ffill, .bfill is deprecated and will change in a future version

the cause is what happens after your merge - the excluded column becomes an object column (the data type has changed). One option is to convert that column back to a boolean, and then the fillna will work without raising a warning. it is interesting though that the column dtype changes

You can use (for pandas 2.2.1 etc) :
dfMainData['excluded'] = dfMainData['excluded'].fillna(0).astype('bool')

which gives
         name other      reason  excluded
0       apple  blah         NaN     False
1        pear  blah  pears suck      True
2      orange  blah         NaN     False
3  watermelon  blah  too messy!      True


One other way is to use the indicator parameter:
dfMainData['excluded'] = dfMainData.merge(dfExclusions, 
                                        how = 'left', 
                                        on = 'name', 
                                        indicator = True)['_merge'].eq('both')
dfMainData
         name other  excluded
0       apple  blah     False
1        pear  blah      True
2      orange  blah     False
3  watermelon  blah      True

